# QWidget - Multi Monitor - Single Desktop - X_CopyArea Bug under Ubuntu

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, qt4, xserver

I can't figure out what's going on with this Bug i got:

```
X Error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 8
Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
Resource id:  0x4e00004
```

I wanted to display two widgets on two Monitors with one Application.
 I configured my Target with the following screen Configuration (Single Desktop, Multiple Monitors):
 [Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-hV1PD2owcHUHVNV1ZVTjV4WWs/edit?usp=sharing)

Weird is the fact that it works for an old X-Server under Suse. Under Ubuntu it doesn't.

Here are source and X-Versions

Btw:
I must use this config (**there must be no virtual Desktop on two screens**), and i just want to get why it doesn't work.
 - Same dirver
 - so qt-bug?

[source.zip can be downloaded here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-hV1PD2owcHWmUxSXZsX0pkSjg/edit?usp=sharing)

```
#include <qapplication.h>
#include <qwidget.h>
#include <qdesktopwidget.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QWidget widgetScreenZero(qApp->desktop()->screen(0));
  QWidget widgetScreenOne(qApp->desktop()->screen(1));
  widgetScreenZero.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/images/zero.svg);");l
  widgetScreenOne.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/images/one.svg);");
  widgetScreenOne.show();
  widgetScreenZero.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

+

```
Suse:
 X.Org X Server 1.8.0
 Release Date: 2010-04-02
 X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
 Build Operating System: openSUSE SUSE LINUX
 Current Operating System: Linux ws17 2.6.34-12-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT 2010-06-29 02:39:08 +0200 i686
 Kernel command line: root=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-KINGSTON_SV100S264G_64GB60076281-part1 resume=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-KINGSTON_SV100S264G_64GB60076281-part2 splash=silent quiet crashkernel= vga=0x345
 Build Date: 05 July 2010 09:26:26PM
 Current version of pixman: 0.18.0
 Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
 to make sure that you have the latest version.
```

+

```
Ubuntu:
 X.Org X Server 1.14.5
 Release Date: 2013-12-12
 X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
 Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.42-37-generic i686 Ubuntu
 Current Operating System: Linux ws25 3.11.0-15-generic #25~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:42:40 UTC 2014 i686
 Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic root=UUID=ce61481b-be95-4a6b-a5db-1f154dc14cd6 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
 Build Date: 06 January 2014 01:41:06PM
 xorg-server 2:1.14.5-1ubuntu2~saucy1~precise2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
 Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
 Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
 to make sure that you have the latest version.
```

Comment: This is either a Qt bug or a Ubuntu bug. I'd report it as a Qt bug first.

Comment: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-37607

Comment: could you show your xorg.conf file for us. maybe your xorg.conf is not right